# How do I specify my app's home-screen icon caption?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I developed an Android scientific calculator with Delphi XE5 and when I tested it on my Samsung Galaxy Advance (Android 2.3.0) I always see "Project1" as file name. Here is a picture:

[image: here].

I want to change this name to "Risolutore Equazioni." How could I do it?

I changed the `label` on the Android manifest xml but nothing happened.

Comment: did you try to uninstall then install the application again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to change it in the manifest (label), use a string resource. Since you said you already did that.. try changing the string "app_name" to the name you want.

Or if it's ready to be exported export as APK and name it when exporting. That's how you'll do to get into the market anyways.

check android dev site 
[here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html)

Answer (score 3):

I fixed my problem by editing the label name in the project options.

1. Project
2. Project Option
3. Version
4. Label
5. I changed with the name I wanted

Answer (score 2):

You can rename the project by right-clicking on the Project name int he Project Manager, and selecting "Rename" from the context menu.

That will rename the project in Android (as in the screenshot above) and also rename the project files, including the .dproj and .dpr files.  It will produce a new .res file, and also appears to produce .deployproj and AndroidManifest.template.xml files.

Don't use this option unless you intend to really rename your whole project.