# Where do I set the application "Title" property in a FireMonkey mobile application?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, firemonkey-fm3

Currently, the project name is used as the caption (title) under the icon on the device's home screen. Unfortunately, this doesn't allow me to use white spaces.

A VCL application has an application "Title" property. You access it from the options form (Application | Appearance | Title). The value you set appears as the caption in the task bar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I specify my app's home-screen icon caption?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18836866/how-do-i-specify-my-apps-home-screen-icon-caption)

Comment: Almost a duplicate, but the other question specifies Android. I'm looking for a solution for all XE5 mobile platforms. It did however point me to the correct answer. Thanks Rob.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The application title can be changed in the **Project Options** dialog under **Version Info**.

For iOS you need to change the **CFBundleDisplayName** property. 
For Android, change the **Label** property.